# Qt. How can I pick default printer and disable the rest of them in QPrinterDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to remove or at least disable all printers but one from "Select printer" group. It is QPrintDialog and I know that it is native. I am interested in solution only for Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.setPrinterName("printer's name");
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setPrinterName