# How can I know which printer is selected

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, printing, qprinter

I have a program with the typical printer dialog (made with QPrintDialog from Qt5.1) where you can select the printer you want from a list. Let's say you have printerA (selected by default), printerB, printerC and printerD. I have a problem with printerD so when the user selects it I want to do something (maybe show a popup message or maybe dissable some buttons).

I've been looking for how to know if printerD is selected but couldn't find it. I've search in [QPrinter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html), [QPrinterInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinterinfo.html), [QPrintDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintdialog.html) and [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done) and I couldn't find it. Also I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468287/qt-how-can-i-pick-default-printer-and-disable-the-rest-of-them-in-qprinterdialo) here which I though it could help me but the answer only tells you how to set the default one.

If you don't know which dialog I am talking about, it's the same from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468287/qt-how-can-i-pick-default-printer-and-disable-the-rest-of-them-in-qprinterdialo).

I also was thinking if this list may be a QListWidget Class but if it was that, i 'don't know how to get it.

So my question is: How may I know which is the printer selected in any moment of this PrinterDialog life? (While showing up).

Also, I want to add, that I tried to dissable the button for the printer which gives me error with the next code but the QList is empty so I can't reach the Print or Preferences Button to dissable it I don't know why:

```
 QList<QPrinterInfo> info_list = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();
 foreach(QPrinterInfo info, info_list)
 {
     if (info.state() == 3) // the printer gives error
     {
        QList<QPushButton *> allButtons = printDialog.findChildren<QPushButton *>();

       for (int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); i++) 
       {
          if (allButtons.at(i)->text().contains("Print") || allButtons.at(i)->text().contains("Preferences"))
          {
           allButtons.at(i)->setDisabled(true);
          }
       }
     }
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the printer name: [`QPrinter::printerName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#printerName).

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog printDialog(printer);
if (printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    // executed after the print dialog is closed and accepted.
    if (printer.printerName() == "printerD") {
        // show a message or do something special ...
    }
    // print ...
}
```

Note that `QPrintDialog` does not provide any method to check the selected printer while the printer dialog is still open (not yet accepted). Using undocumented hacks such as using `findChildren` will not work in a cross platform way as native print dialog may be used[[1]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintdialog.html#details):

> On Windows and macOS, the native print dialog is used, which means
> that some QWidget and QDialog properties set on the dialog won't be
> respected. The native print dialog on macOS does not support setting
> printer options, i.e. setOptions() and setOption() have no effect.

If you really want/need to determine printer selection in realtime, you should implement your own custom printer dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the help. i was afraid that i couldn't use i as it is native. I tried to use it as you said but it didn't work as when the  `.exec()` is executed it opens the print dialog and stays there so if I select different printers on the list, it is not aware of it but thank you anyway.

Comment: [`QDialog::exec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) indeed opens a dialog and only returns after the dialog is closed.

Comment: yes, that's why I was looking for something to do while it was open because I have a crash inside it so I need an action to be done before closing it

Comment: If the crash occurs inside the print dialog, it may be better to report it as a Qt bug, or as a driver bug of your printer. If the user should not use this printer, deinstalling it may be the best solution. You could consider asking a separate question about the crash you encounter.